# How to get value of radio button that is checked after clicking label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came up with a way to get the value of the radio button by connecting for and id.
But I couldn't come up with a method other than using for.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="1" id="id_1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="2" id="id_2">
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="3" id="id_3">

  <ul>
    <li><label for="id_1">id_1</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_2">id_2</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_3">id_3</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('label').on('click', function(){
      // Not working as intended
      console.log(`Not working as intended: ${$(this).parents('div').find('input:checked').val()}`);
      console.log($("input[name='group']:checked").val());

      // It works.But I want to know how to not use for
      console.log(`It works: ${$(`input#${$(this).attr('for')}`).val()}`);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is you are handling the click on the label and reporting *before* the radio button selection actually changes.

Instead of binding to click on the label, bind an event handler to the *change* event on the radio buttons themselves.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="1" id="id_1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="2" id="id_2">
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="3" id="id_3">

  <ul>
    <li><label for="id_1">id_1</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_2">id_2</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_3">id_3</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
        let div = $(this).parents('div')[0];
        console.log('the parent div is:', div);
        let selected = div.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
        console.log('selected is:', selected);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am I correct in saying that if the event is a click, it is not possible to get the changed radio button value?

Comment: @eternalnovice - no, that statement is not correct. It _is_ possible, it is just more complicated.  Another problem with using click is ... what if the radio-button selection is changed without using click? I can tab to a radio button and use arrow-keys to change which one is selected; in that case the click event handler is never fired (which is ok if the only thing the handler is for is to change the radio button)

Comment: I wanted to add ... right now you are just doing some `console.log(...)` statements, but think about what you're _really_ trying to do. If what you are really doing is because a radio button is being chosen then the `change` event is definitely more logical and descriptive than a `click` event. Think ... "I'm doing X because the radio button Y was selected" then what you are doing is because the value, which radio was chosen, has _changed_, not because some label was _clicked_. Thinking like that helps you determine which element(s) and what event(s) you should care about.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and polite answer. I was stuck with the click event. . . It seems I was thinking in the wrong direction. I learned a lot. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `change` handler for the radio buttons instead of a `click` handler for the labels.

For example:

```
$('input[name="group"]').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work as intended.

Comment: Oh, what do you want? I think you want to get checked radio value. is it right? If not, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing explanation. I want to get the value of the radio button after it has been changed.

Comment: If so, I updated my answer. please check it.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. I was able to get the value of the radio button after the change.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it works fine for you.